# SWTableViewCell cannot select cell in UItableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swipe

I have implemented the `SWTableView`. Its working fine.
But when i swipes quickly from right to left then swipes close
This issue: Cell in `UITableView` cannot select

[Swipe right to left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXvVf.jpg)

[Cannot select cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zY5V.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your Gesture Recogniser taking the select event of Cell.
You can check this by keeping breakpoint on your gesture method when select the cell.